# Echo not printing anything (It was before)

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a bit of a headache with a echo on my php code, the problem is that it isn't printing anything on screen, even though it was before, granted I added a function but when I used firebug to debug it it showed that it was getting the information out of a database correctly, just not printing it on-screen.

Where a list should be displayed there is nothing but empty space, staring into my soul.

I would appreciated if someone could point me out if I am missing something, as well why it is happening so I many not have to bother anyone anymore and if needed share my newly acquired knowledge.

PHP

```
function displayInfoLabs(){  

if(isset($_POST['pId'])){

    $id = $_POST['pId'];

        $info = getSpecificLabs($id);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($info)){
echo '<ul>' .
        '<li>Laboratorio # ' . $row['codigolab'] . '</li>' .
        '<li>Capacidad: ' . $row['capacidad'] . '</li>' .
        '<li>Carrera: ' . $row['carrera'] . '</li>' .
        '<li>Ubicación: ' . $row['ubicacion'] . '</li>' .
     '</ul>';

   }
  }
 }


function getSpecificLabs($pId){  


 $query = "SELECT bk.idlab , bk.codigolab , bk.capacidad, bk.carrera, bk.ubicacion FROM labs as bk WHERE bk.idlab = $pId";

 $result = do_query($query);

 return $result;
}
```

For reference I am also including the html and JS code of this function.

JS

```
$("#lnkInfo").click(function() {
  var id = $('#txtId').val();


 var request = $.ajax({
  url: "includes/functionsLabs.php",
  type: "post",
  data: {

    'call': 'displayInfoLabs',
    'pId':id},

    dataType: 'json',

success: function(response){
        alert('exito')

    }
  });
});
```

HTML created via PHP, mind the lnkInfo which calls the JS that in turn calls the PHP

```
function displayList(){

 $lista = getLabs();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($lista)){
echo 
      '<div class="box" id="lab'.$row['idlab'].'">
          <p id="labName">Lab #'.$row['codigolab'] . '</p>
          <p class="info"><a href="#" id="lnkInfo">Info</p></a>
          <p class="info"><a href="reservarLab.html">Reservar</p></a>
          <input type="hidden" name="txtId" id="txtId" value="'.$row['idlab'].'">
      </div>';
 }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT:**

Changing the success function made the list appear but it overrode the div's style including the buttons it had and all. This is the div's code.

```
div class="popUp1 hide" id="popUpCorrecto1">
        <div class="estiloPopUp">
          <span>Información de laboratorio</span>
          <span value="Cerrar" id="btnCerrar">x</span>
        </div>



          <input type = "button" value = "Eliminar" id = "btnEliminar" onclick="eliminar()" />
          <input type = "button" value = "Modificar" id = "btnModificar"  onclick="window.location='modificarLab.html';" />

        </div>
```

Comment: you set `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax request meaning you expect json to be returned, yet you're returning `text/html`. Change that to `dataType: 'text/html'`, provided the request runs successfully and returns status 200.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.

Comment: Does your php error log list any warnings or errors?

Comment: @Darren I will try it right now! Thanks for the swift reply. The alert was triggered though

Comment: @Raptor, thanks I am rather new to all this so all of your advices are very welcome.

Comment: @chemBlob9999 No error at all, it didn't print thats it.

Comment: @Darren, I did as you told me but it isn't showing anything yet. Again I tried running it with firebug at it showed that the data was captured but wasn't printing.

Comment: Can you try to echo a simple string like 'string' (instead of $row['x']) and see if this string is echoed? If it is, your query might be empty. Replace your entire echoed <div>...</div> or <ul>...</ul> with 'string'

Comment: @ChemBlob9999 I did and nothing showed up, which is weird because using the exact same code (with json) but without the getSpecificLabs() function it was working before. I though it may be a problem with the function itself but again firebug says it is retriving the information succesfully. Could the problem be on the while?

Comment: Also it is worth nothing that the echo <div> IS working while, the echo <ul> isn't.

Comment: your $pid is int or string?

Comment: @user3517652  var id = $('#txtId').val(); then 'pId':id

Comment: In $query, I think WHERE bk.idlab = $pId - needs to be - WHERE bk.idlab = '$pId' ....try $pId in quotes

Comment: @ChemBlob9999 I tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in the comments, your data is being captured, but you aren't appending it to the document. you are simply doing:

```
alert('exito');
```

What you want to do is append the response to an element that is present in your page.

For examples sake, we can put a **`<div>`** with the id of **`mydata`** like so:

```
<div id="mydata"></div>
```

Now in your [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) function, you could do something like the following:

```
$("#lnkInfo").click(function() {
  var id = $('#txtId').val();


 var request = $.ajax({
  url: "includes/functionsLabs.php",
  type: "post",
  data: {

    'call': 'displayInfoLabs',
    'pId':id},

    dataType: 'text/html',

success: function(response){
        $('#mydata').html(response);

    }
  });
});
```

As you can see in the above, we modified your `success` function to include

```
$('#mydata').html(response);
```

provided all your data is printed and supplied correctly, it should display on the page.

### EDIT:

<s>it seems in your PHP query</s>

```
$query = "SELECT bk.idlab , bk.codigolab , bk.capacidad, bk.carrera, bk.ubicacion FROM labs as bk WHERE bk.idlab = $pId";
```

You are selecting the columns prefixed with **`bk.*`** yet trying to print out the values without the prefix as seen below:

```
     echo '<ul>' .
        '<li>Laboratorio # ' . $row['codigolab'] . '</li>' .
        '<li>Capacidad: ' . $row['capacidad'] . '</li>' .
        '<li>Carrera: ' . $row['carrera'] . '</li>' .
        '<li>Ubicación: ' . $row['ubicacion'] . '</li>' .
     '</ul>';
```

Try changing the above to something like:

```
     echo '<ul>' .
        '<li>Laboratorio # ' . $row['bk.codigolab'] . '</li>' .
        '<li>Capacidad: ' . $row['bk.capacidad'] . '</li>' .
        '<li>Carrera: ' . $row['bk.carrera'] . '</li>' .
        '<li>Ubicación: ' . $row['bk.ubicacion'] . '</li>' .
     '</ul>';
```

If i understood it correctly.

**Edit:** ignore above php examples.

Change the `success` function from:

```
$('#mydata').html(response);
```

to

```
$('#mydata').append(response);
```

As `.html()` replaces all content within the specified element with the supplied content.

**EDIT #2:**

From the comments, you're ajax request is run every time that **`#LnkInfo`** is triggered which seems like it happens a lot as it loads the PopUp?

What you want to do is add in some logic, either in your jQuery function that checks if you've already appended the list to the popup and to stop it appending.

That could be done simply by adding a boolean variable somewhere in there.
Alternatively, you could just add a little div on that popup that you append it to.

Example:

This is your popup:

```
div class="popUp1 hide" id="popUpCorrecto1">
        <div class="estiloPopUp">
          <span>Información de laboratorio</span>
          <span value="Cerrar" id="btnCerrar">x</span>
        </div>

        <!-- ADDED A NEW DIV HERE FOR LIST CONTENT -->
        <div id="mylistcontent"></div>

          <input type = "button" value = "Eliminar" id = "btnEliminar" onclick="eliminar()" />
          <input type = "button" value = "Modificar" id = "btnModificar"  onclick="window.location='modificarLab.html';" />

        </div>
```

As you can see above, I've added the following:

```
<!-- ADDED A NEW DIV HERE FOR LIST CONTENT -->
            <div id="mylistcontent"></div>
```

Now in your jQuery `success` function, you could append to that **`#mylistcontent`** div instead of the popup div :)

Comment: The weirdest thing happened. I did what you said and nothing happened, so I putted html instead of json again. The info was finally displayed (I can still hear the chorus of the Hallelujah) but the div's style I was using (because the ul was going inside a list) got completely ovverrided, including two buttons and all.

Comment: Good :) I'm a bit confused with your last sentence, what do you mean including two buttons?

Comment: Changing the ul to bk. yields:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\wamp\www\Proyecto\includes\functionsLabs.php on line 118

Comment: By the way using prefix .bk does work with the div I am creating in the function below my original code, and it was working for this one before I added the function where it gets the data from idlab=$id

Comment: You're awesome you know that? It worked! BUT two things happened, one is that the buttons of the div I happened went crazy and floated to the roof (no biggie I can fix that in css) and the other which I think is a logical fallacy of mine is that if I close the "popUp" and open it again clicking the link with lnkInfo it displays the list + a replica of the list. Meaning it creates a list each time XD unless I refresh.

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper Okay good. That issue would be because every time you click on the `#LnkInfo` it runs the ajax request and appends the data to the div. You need to set up something in your code to check if you've already appended the data, if so, don't run the query, otherwise run the query. I will add an example edit now.

Comment: Awesome! That totally fixed the style, even though if I click lnkInfo it still adds more replicas of the list, I will try to implement your boolean suggestion as well!

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper if you go with the seperate list content div option, you could simple do the `html()` instead of `append()` and that would fix your problems :)

Comment: Because each time it click that instead of adding more it overrides what I already had... Damn! That logic is priceless, thanks A LOT. I cannot even begin to describe how grateful I am.

Comment: I noticed that if I add another lab (div) it won't show me the list or open the popUp I suspect that is because I am using lnkInfo as a Id and not a class, thankfully what would have been a horrible setback is nothing but something I think I will be able to fix in minutes thanks to the easy, clean code and advice you have provided me. Again thanks a lot for taking time out of your life to help a noob like me, I won't even forget it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50720/discussion-between-code-grasshopper-and-darren)